# About a static value in function's parameter in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, reference, call

what should be the output of this code below? and why?
I am not sure if the int i declared in the main function acts like a local variable, or not.

```
static int i = 3;
void f(int*j){
    j++;
}
int g(int* j){
    return i+=*j;
}
void h(int j, int k){

    printf("%d,%d,%d\n", i,j,k);

}
int main(){
     int i = 3;
     int j = 5;
     int *p = &i;
     f(&i);
     f(p);
     for(;i<5;i++){
        *p = g(p);
    }
    h(i,j);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These calls of the function `f`

```
 f(&i);
 f(p);
```

have no effect.

Within the function g there is changed the global variable i

```
int g(int* j){
    return i+=*j;
}
```

As the function is called in the loop

```
 for(;i<5;i++){
    *p = g(p);
}
```

one time for `i` equal to `3` then the global variable `i` will be equal to `i + 3 = 6`. The local variable `i` will be equal to the returned value of the global variable `i` (equal to 6) from the function and then will be incremented in the loop. So after exiting the loop it will be equal to `7`..

This call

```
h(i,j);
```

outputs the global variable `i` and passed as arguments the local variables `i` and `j`. So its output will be `6,7,5`.